# Is it possible to render HTML in gmail

Tags: html, gmail, html-email

If I send this message

```
<h5>Hello</h5>

<h3 style="color:pink">GOODBYE</h3>
```

It appears as it is.

Is there any way to render the same message as HTML at receivers end?

update :

what i want on receivers side is :
Hello (style corresponding to the h5 tag)
GOODBYE (style corresponding to the h3 tag & in pink color)

Comment: *How* do you send this message?

Comment: For e.g when i'm sending email to someone and my email body is:  "how are you ?" in bold ... my email will be send as <b> how are you ? </b>.   How can i insert this " <b> how are you ? </b> " directly in my html page. ? i m using http://textangular.com/.

Comment: @MaxArt in short  whole thing is being sent to gmail in string

Comment: @DineshChander gmail do support HTML Email, not directly though. 
Actually it is like a WUSIWUG editor, without allowing u to write code. I tested an emailer template and it worked

Comment: @DineshChander You didn't answer at all. *What* are you using to send the mail? Your mail client? Using a library like Javamail, PHPMailer, whatever?

Comment: @MaxArt:  what i m doing is .. i m fetching emails from gmail programmatically and then trying to show those mails on html page but i m getting html tags in the message which should not be the case.. btw i m using node js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send HTML images in Google's gmail web interface; this interface converts al HTML tags to the human readable variant, so they get isplayed as-is on the other side.

Your alternative is to set up an **SMTP server** (they usually come with your ISP) and send e-mails from there. You can set the 'from' field yourself, so you can change that to your gmail account. The disadvantage is that your mail will likely be caught in spamfilters.

Good luck!

Comment: You can also send images, infact you can send the Full Styled HTML Email provided all external files have abslute links, and you copy the Viusual Mode. Thats it Try copying a simple webpage with images and paste in gmail. it works.

Answer (score 4):

Google does not accepts user's custom html. < > is converted as &lt; &gt; so it displayed in browser as < > , Thats all. you can't use your coding.

Comment: sorry rahiil if my question is not clear but this isn't what i want ? i want to show emails directly on my page . but i am getting html tags along with messages

Answer (score 2):

so it is completely possible to render HTML code inside an email. I've only tried it through the gmail client though. It is slightly "hacky" but works perfectly.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsMSqhMlfao

Look at this video, it highlights the steps in a fairly simple way, but there are some things you will have to change. Once you hit inspect on your dummy text, you can't just double click to edit the code, it gets pasted in as Weird text comments.

[image: Not Working]

Instead, hit the "edit as HTML" button instead and remove the double quotes, pasting your code in directly. You'll be able to tell that you've done it right when your tags etc. display the way the rest of the code around it does. (I had locally linked images so they didn't show)

[image: Working]

Comment: This. It is also possible to paste _already rendered_ HTML (from another website, for example Wikipedia) into the gmail editor: for instance, take an `<h1>` tag with an `<hr>` below it, and some text below that `<hr>`, such as a Wikipedia article. Select everything from the header to the start of the text, copy and paste into gmail. Both the `<h1>` tag and the `<hr>` (and any other HTML tag AFAIK) **will render on the receiving end**. I suggest you edit this in, as this method and yours are the only correct answers here. This only works for **rendered** HTML, not the HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to send it from an external platform to arrive at the gmail inbox. Try something like SendBlaster (free download) or MailChimp (online interface)